# Pine Script Cool-down for a certain number of bars

Tags: pine-script

I use the following code with "barssince" in Pine Script to get buy signals after a cooldown of 4 bars.

```
cooldown = ta.barssince(buySignal[1]) > 3 ? buySignal : na 
plotshape(cooldown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, style=shape.triangleup, text="YEY")
```

In the following table I try to explain "what I want", which is another way of counting the candles. Candle # 1 and candle # 6 are marked correct. Candle # 11 should be yes, but considering the logic of "barssince" it is the 4. candle since the last signal, but it is the 5. candle since the last "yes" from the cooldown function. I hope you understand what I mean. How should the function look like?

| Candle # | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| buySignal | yes | no | no | no | no | yes | yes | no | no | no | yes |
| buySignal with cooldown | yes | no | no | no | no | yes | no | no | no | no | no |
| candles since buySignal with cooldown | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| what I want | yes | no | no | no | no | yes | no | no | no | no | yes |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable to mark if your signal along with your cooldown counter become `true`. Then just increment the counter and check with your condition again and then reset your variable.

Here, I have a simple buy condition (`close > 40000`). It will then mark every fifth candle where `close > 40000`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
var bool isBought = false
var cnt = 0
buySignal = close > 40000

if not isBought and buySignal
    isBought := true
    cnt := 0
    
cnt := cnt + 1
bool coolDown = cnt > 4 and buySignal

if coolDown
    isBought := false
    
plotshape(series=coolDown, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, location=location.belowbar)
hline(price=40000, linestyle=hline.style_solid, linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!
Instead of choosing the numbers of candles, is it possible to set a timeframe like 1h/1D?

Comment: It is possible but it is more tricky. If you need that you can ask a new question.

Comment: I have the feeling, there is a mistake in the script: On some 1st bars with a buy signal, the triangleup is not displayed after using the script above. As there is no bar before with a buy signal, this does not makes sense. This is quite strange, because actually your script should work. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: The solution might be to put "cnt := 0" in the last if. To be honest, I cannot explain why it does not work, if it is in the first condition. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: I can have a look but could you please edit your question and add a screenshot where this happens. Please make sure that the ticker, timeframe and date is visible in the screenshot so I can test too.

Comment: Currently I do not have access to the script, but you should be able to replicate it by moving the cnt := 0 expression from the first if to the second if condition. Just try some different inputs instead of "4" in both scripts and you should see the difference.